# Setar um campo em todas os models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenancy

Estou tentando criar um app que funciona com varias empresas e preciso sempre gravar o campo *company_id* sempre que criar e/ou atualizar qualquer **model**, qual a melhor maneira de se fazer isto?

Pensei em um *before_action* em todo **models**, mas recebo um

```
undefined method `before_action' for #<Class:0x007fcfd9438d38>
```

Um dos models é este:

```
class Config < ApplicationRecord
  before_action :set_current_user

  def set_current_user
    User.current = current_user
  end

  belongs_to :company

validates :company_id, uniqueness: true

  dragonfly_accessor :logo

  before_save :set_company

  private
    def set_company
      self.company_id = current_user.company_id
    end
end
```

Comment: Boa tarde, pode postar o código do Model?

Comment: Na verdade, olhando seu código, você está usando um `before_save` para esta finalidade. Certo? Mas o erro vem do `before_action`, como você disse? Qual seria a lógica do seu método `set_current_user` ? Você está setando um atributo `current` na classe `User`. Este atributo existe no model User? Pode elaborar um pouco mais? o seu `before_save` parece OK

Comment: o `set_current_user` vem do devise, mas ele não está disponível nos models, e o `company_id` já esta gravado na seção do usuário cadastrado, então pensei em usar isto para setar em todos os métodos, já que cada usuário deve sr somente dados de sua empresa.

Comment: O código acima parece estar OK, qual o erro que retorna dele? Tentou simular uma inserção pelo console?

Comment: Tanto no browser quanto no console recebo a mensagem `Config.find_by_company_id(1)
NoMethodError: undefined method `before_action' for #<Class:0x00000008adea78>
Did you mean?  before_commit
from /home/adell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:21:in `method_missing'`

Comment: Tenta substituir aquele primeiro `before_action` por `before_save`, já que `before_action` é um callback do controller, e não do model. O seu `before_save` do `set_company` que você citou na pergunta parece ok.

Comment: É isto mesmo, o problema aparentemente é que `before_action` não deve ser usado no model.